# angulartics2 and angular1.6 compatibility

Tags: compatibility, angular1.6, angulartics2

Is angulartics2 compatible with angular1.6

OR

Is angulartics compatible with angular2

Because I'm currently working with angular 1.6 and I plan to migrate to angular2 in the future, and I'm searching for a solution that is compatible with both

Answer (score 0):

There's two "versions" available:

[angulartics](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics)
and
[angulartics2](https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2)

As you can see, the first one is for Angular 1.x, where as the second one is for Angular 2/4/5.

I have not worked with either version, but my guess is that migrating your entire app from Angular 1.6 to Angular 2/4/5 will take a good amount of work anyways, so exchanging these plugins with one another shouldn't be ***that*** much of a problem.

So, in a way, **no**. This plugin isn't exactly the solution you need considering it is supposed to work in both versions. I highly doubt there's a solution available that will just work out of the box for both versions to be all honest.